# Using Jenkins Parameterized Remote Trigger Plugin With File Parameters

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

## Question:

I'm trying to run a Jenkins job remotely from a different Jenkins instance using the Jenkins Parameterized Remote Trigger plugin.
**Is there a way to pass File parameters into the downstream job using the plugin?**

I'm trying to find a way to run a Jenkins job remotely from another Jenkins instance, while also waiting for the downstream job to finish and getting it's result.
The Jenkins Parameterized Remote Trigger plugin does that perfectly when I only input string parameters:

```
def handle = triggerRemoteJob job: 'http://my-jenkins-instance/job/my-job-name', parameters: 'param1=abc\nparam2=xyz'
```

But the main question is, is there a way to pass File parameters aswell? Or do I need to find a different solution. (And if so, *what is the best way to run a job remotely from a different instance while also waiting for it to finish and getting the job's result?*).

Answer (score 2):

I do not think the [Jenkins Parameterized Remote Trigger plugin](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/Parameterized-Remote-Trigger/) natively supports file parameters.

You could work around this limitation by uploading the file to a shared location accessible to both Jenkins instances and passing the file URL or path as a string parameter.

```
def fileUrl = 'http://shared-location/path/to/file'
def handle = triggerRemoteJob job: 'http://my-jenkins-instance/job/my-job-name', 
                              parameters: "param1=abc\nparam2=xyz\nfileUrl=${fileUrl}"
```

In the downstream job, you can then use a script to download the file from the shared location.

---

If you need a more direct method to pass file parameters or want an alternative approach for running jobs remotely, you might consider:

- [SSH Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ssh/): use SSH to directly execute commands on the remote Jenkins instance. That can include file transfer commands.
- Use the Jenkins REST API to trigger jobs and upload files.
- If both Jenkins instances have access to a shared file system, you can place files there and reference them in your jobs.
- Use an artifact repository like [Nexus](https://www.sonatype.com/products/sonatype-nexus-repository) or [Artifactory](https://jfrog.com/blog/what-is-artifactory-jfrog/) to store files, and pass the artifact URL as a parameter.